# mongoimport/mongoexport and timeseries

Tags: mongodb, time-series, mongoimport, mongoexport

Do the `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` cli tools support the new timeseries collection type?

We are trying to exporting data from a timeseries collection:

```
mongoexport -h localhost --port=27018 --type=json --db=tstest -c tsdata
```

and we get the following error:

```
connected to: mongodb://localhost:27018/
Failed: (CommandNotSupportedOnView) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Namespace tstest.tsdata is a timeseries collection
```

to resolve the issue I need to fake a query statement like this:

```
mongoexport -h localhost --port=27018 --type=json --db=tstest -c tsdata -q="{}"
```

but this let me suspect that the tool has something wrong.

Not only, if I need to import a JSON data set using `mongoimport` I have another issue, for every imported record into the timeseries collection there is no way to not create the `_id` field

```
mongoimport -h localhost --port=27018 --type=json --db=tstest -c tsdata --file=rawdata.json
```

the file has many rows like this

```
{ "metadata": {"feedId": "fd::6022a06ba3d9e1001969c92f", "assetId": "fd::5fc900afce5a0300198df68a" }, "timestamp": { "$date" : "2022-04-05T10:48:50.908Z" }, "value": 74 }
...
```

and on my db, after the import, all my timeseries record has this form

```
/* 1 */
{
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2022-04-05T10:48:50.908Z"),
    "metadata" : {
        "assetId" : "fd::5fc900afce5a0300198df68a",
        "feedId" : "fd::6022a06ba3d9e1001969c92f"
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("624c03ca560bfaa462084f85"),
    "value" : 74
}
```

but I don't want to put that extra data on every record.
Is there any solution?

I'm using mongod version 5.0.6.

Comment: `_id` is a mandatory field - you provide the value or the MongoDB driver/server assigns it.

Comment: not for timeseries collection, timeseries does not need to have it, and they don't use it, so it is wasted space

Comment: Instead of mongoimport and mongoexport - maybe you can try mongodump and mongorestore.

Comment: no, I have a file full of JSON line data and I want to import it, I don't have a dump

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: I've put a sample in the post

Comment: The JSON document imported into a timeseries collection (MongoDB v5.0.6) without any issues.

Comment: but on the DB you have or you don't have the field "_id" on any document?

Comment: When I imported the sample JSON, the import created document in the collection - and the document has an `_id` field (as expected).

Comment: why expected? timeseries collection does not use "_id".